# Oracle Apex Dynamic Action to reload/refresh a button

Tags: modal-dialog, oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex I got an Interactive Grid that when you click on a row, a page item P530_NETGEBIED is set. This works. I also have a button to a modal dialog, where I want to set de P530_NETGEBIED to be set: P531_NETGEBIED.

This does not work, because the button is made when page 530 was first loaded. So the page item can be set, but the link does not set the page item in the modal dialog.

Thanks in advance!

There are two ways to solve this:

- Set the link to 'redirect to url' and then use a Javascript function that updates the url if p530_netgebid is changed. This works, but I want to refresh after this modal dialog closes. That does not work, because the modal dialog is opened with 'redirect to URL'.
- Reload this button to the modal dialog after the page item changes (with dynamic action). But how do I do that?

Comment: Does [this](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/05/passing-data-in-and-out-of-apex-dialogs/) help ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you save the value of :P530_NETGEBIED to session state, and then read it when you open your modal dialog box?